# Email serial code for digial product after paypal payment

Tags: paypal

Basically, I want so that when someone purchases a serial code from my website for a product using PayPal, once the payment is received, it sends an email with a UNIQUE serial code (from a database?) to the email on the buyer's PayPal account. Anyone know of good software or way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Notification), which sends a message to the listener on your server when a transaction is done. Then you can decide according to the IPN message if your system should send out a serial. (You will have to develop the listener and designate the URL of this listener when you initiate the PayPal transaction.)

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

IPN does more than that but the above URL could be the starting point.

However if you are asking which software generates the serial, that's out of my knowledge.

Comment: I have the serial codes I would want to use but I figured there was a program out there that has a configurable easy to use listener, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you completely. Just would like to say, the way you handle IPN is decided by how your business handle the orders, and thus it's highly related to your specific scenarios. That's why many people and even PayPal would only give you an idea of how to handle the verification of IPN, but wouldn't say much about how you deal with the orders. That said, many 3rd party shopping carts, such as Magento and other frameworks, have their own standard ways to deal with IPN and orders, but you would have to deal with the installation and setup of such a framework.